# Autoconnect option in socket.io client

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I my app I use socket.io. Inside the client code I use

```
    let socket;
    const connect = () => {
        let error = null;

        socket = io({autoConnect: false});

        socket.on('connect', () => {
            console.log('Connected');
          });
         socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
            console.log(`Disconnected: ${error || reason}`);
            error = null;
         });
         socket.on('message', (message) => {
            $("#messages").append(message + '<br/>');
            let last = document.querySelector('#messages').lastElementChild;
            last.scrollIntoView();
         });

         socket.open();
    }
```

But it looks like that `enter code here

```
 socket = io({autoConnect: false});
```

So not work well. Every time I open the side from node server, node reports a connection. Is there a problem in my syntax? I assume that the auto connect will avoid this case so the connection is only done when call connect().

Answer (score 2):

I think

```
socket = io({autoConnect: false, reconnection: false});
```

is the solution